# SQL Server 2014 Can sensitive data be hidden or obfuscated from developers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Maybe I'm  searching with wrong keywords or maybe it cannot be done (unlikely). I will purchase SQL S 2014 Developer edition if it can do so.

Basically some columns in some tables have sensitive info. I do not want developers to see the true content. I'm sure I saw something about this some time ago but I just cannot find it - or was I dreaming?

Comment: seems like you wantto 'encrypt a column of data'. Did you search on that?

Comment: Thanks 'encrypt' was the missing search term.

Answer (score 0):

The others are right it sounds as though using encryption here would be the Right Thing.

Alternatively, you can DENY the permission to SELECT those columns as Column Permissions under the Table Properties:

DENY SELECT ON [SubscriptionOrders] ([CreditCardNum]) TO [Dev]

Or you could DENY access to that entire table (or database) for everyone but DBAs, and CREATE a VIEW that queries that table except for the said column for which it returns the empty value ''

Or combine the permissions strategy with the Right Thing and do the Righteous Thing.